# JavaScript / jQuery - Any way to detect click type?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclicklistener, jquery-click-event

In my code I use `jQuery`'s `click()` function. Is there any way to detect click **type**? For example the ability to differentiate between **mouse** clicks and **code driven** clicks?

Comment: What do you mean by code driven clicks? I know that, but need to know more.

Comment: I mean "code initiated" clicks, like using jQuery's `click` function. I want to distinguish between user's mouse click, and my code's automated clicks.

Comment: You mean, `.trigger("click")` and `.click()`?

Comment: It's very likely that there would be much cleaner way to do whatever it is you try to do. Like, `$('elem').click( function() { doSomething(true); })` where the parameter to `doSomething` tells if it's a user click, and in code instead of triggering the click call `doSomething(false)`.

Comment: @undroid Tell me if it is working for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me `e.originalEvent` is you need:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e){
    if (e.originalEvent === undefined) {
        alert ('triggered by code');
    }else {
        alert ('triggered by mouse');
    }
});
```

Or may be you would try sending the extra event data to have a check.

Another option is to have a check for `e.isTrigger` like:

```
$('button').on('click', function (e) {
    if (e.isTrigger) {
        alert ('triggered by code');
    }else {
        alert ('triggered by mouse');
    }
});
```

Comment: Elegant and clean, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When it is clicked physically by mouse, the `event` has these properties:

```
clientX: 
clientY:
```

So, if they are `undefined`, it is programmatic.

```js
$(function () {
  $("#btn").click(function (e) {
    console.log(typeof e.clientX);
    if (typeof e.clientX == "number")
      alert("Mouse Click");
    else
      alert("Programmatic");
  });
  $("#pxy").click(function (e) {
    $("#btn").click();
  });
});
```

```css
* {font-family: 'Segoe UI'; font-size: 10pt;}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="btn" />
<input type="button" value="Click the Button" id="pxy" />
```

Comment: cool, also thought about checking if mousemove was updated x time before click or if it was a touch event for other devices

Comment: @johnSmith ***Note:** I used `console.dir()` to find stuff.*

Comment: Thanks @PraveenKumar, good answer. Although your answer meets my requirements, I selected Jai's answer because It is a bit more easier to read.

Comment: @undroid Sure... I agree with that too... `:)` Coz that's the right way.